# ¿por qué mi código no llena toda la matriz en Javascript con recursividad?

Tags: javascript, algoritmos, matrices, recursión

El programa lo hice en Javascript pero no funcionaba, así que lo adapté a java y el algoritmo funciona bien, sólo me da problemas en javascript, cuando lo implemento en java sí me muestra 10 filas de números aleatorios al momento de correrlo, en javascript me muestra 10 filas con números aleatorios, pero las 10 filas son las mismas, imprime 10 números aleatorios en una fila y esa fila la imprime 10 veces, soy nuevo ahí, así que no sé si me haya equivocado en alguna función especial que tenga javascript, este es el código:

```
let datos = [10,10];

//Este es el método para recorrer las filas
function recursivo(i){
    if(i<0)
        return 0;
    else{
        //llama a otro método recursivo para llenar cada fila
        llenar(i,9);
        return recursivo(i-1);
    }
}

function llenar(i,n){
    if(n<0)
        return 0;
    else{
        //lleno cada celda con un número aleatorio
        datos[i,n] = Math.round((Math.random()*10)+1);
        return llenar(i,n-1);
    }
}

//Método para recorrer las filas de la matriz
function mostrar(i){
    if(i<0)
        return 0;
    else{
        //Llamo a otro método recursivo para mostrar cada celda
        enseñar(i,9);        
        console.log("\n");
        return mostrar(i-1);
    }
}

//Método reursivo para mostrar las celdas
function enseñar(i,n){
    if(n<0)
        return 0;
    else{
        console.log("Celda: " + i + " " + n + " " + datos[i,n]);
        return enseñar(i,n-1);
    }
}

//Aquí llamo a los métodos, primero lleno la matriz
recursivo(9);
//Aquí muestro la matriz
mostrar(9);
```

Esto es lo que muestra la consola cuando lo corro en Javascript,sólo me genera 10 números aleatorios y esos mismos me los muestra 10 veces:

```
Celda: 9 9 3
Celda: 9 8 7
Celda: 9 7 11
Celda: 9 6 2
Celda: 9 5 9
Celda: 9 4 3
Celda: 9 3 8
Celda: 9 2 5
Celda: 9 1 8
Celda: 9 0 2


Celda: 8 9 3
Celda: 8 8 7
Celda: 8 7 11
Celda: 8 6 2
Celda: 8 5 9
Celda: 8 4 3
Celda: 8 3 8
Celda: 8 2 5
Celda: 8 1 8
Celda: 8 0 2


Celda: 7 9 3
Celda: 7 8 7
Celda: 7 7 11
Celda: 7 6 2
Celda: 7 5 9
Celda: 7 4 3
Celda: 7 3 8
Celda: 7 2 5
Celda: 7 1 8
Celda: 7 0 2


Celda: 6 9 3
Celda: 6 8 7
Celda: 6 7 11
Celda: 6 6 2
Celda: 6 5 9
Celda: 6 4 3
Celda: 6 3 8
Celda: 6 2 5
Celda: 6 1 8
Celda: 6 0 2


Celda: 5 9 3
Celda: 5 8 7
Celda: 5 7 11
Celda: 5 6 2
Celda: 5 5 9
Celda: 5 4 3
Celda: 5 3 8
Celda: 5 2 5
Celda: 5 1 8
Celda: 5 0 2


Celda: 4 9 3
Celda: 4 8 7
Celda: 4 7 11
Celda: 4 6 2
Celda: 4 5 9
Celda: 4 4 3
Celda: 4 3 8
Celda: 4 2 5
Celda: 4 1 8
Celda: 4 0 2


Celda: 3 9 3
Celda: 3 8 7
Celda: 3 7 11
Celda: 3 6 2
Celda: 3 5 9
Celda: 3 4 3
Celda: 3 3 8
Celda: 3 2 5
Celda: 3 1 8
Celda: 3 0 2


Celda: 2 9 3
Celda: 2 8 7
Celda: 2 7 11
Celda: 2 6 2
Celda: 2 5 9
Celda: 2 4 3
Celda: 2 3 8
Celda: 2 2 5
Celda: 2 1 8
Celda: 2 0 2


Celda: 1 9 3
Celda: 1 8 7
Celda: 1 7 11
Celda: 1 6 2
Celda: 1 5 9
Celda: 1 4 3
Celda: 1 3 8
Celda: 1 2 5
Celda: 1 1 8
Celda: 1 0 2


Celda: 0 9 3
Celda: 0 8 7
Celda: 0 7 11
Celda: 0 6 2
Celda: 0 5 9
Celda: 0 4 3
Celda: 0 3 8
Celda: 0 2 5
Celda: 0 1 8
Celda: 0 0 2
```

Lo que quiero que me muestre es que sean números aleatorios en cada celda, como por ejemplo en java, si ejecuto el mismo algoritmo en java, me da el resultado esperado, el cual es:

```
Celda: 9 9 9
Celda: 9 8 5
Celda: 9 7 6
Celda: 9 6 8
Celda: 9 5 6
Celda: 9 4 2
Celda: 9 3 8
Celda: 9 2 4
Celda: 9 1 3
Celda: 9 0 1


Celda: 8 9 4
Celda: 8 8 9
Celda: 8 7 1
Celda: 8 6 7
Celda: 8 5 8
Celda: 8 4 8
Celda: 8 3 10
Celda: 8 2 9
Celda: 8 1 2
Celda: 8 0 7


Celda: 7 9 9
Celda: 7 8 9
Celda: 7 7 9
Celda: 7 6 9
Celda: 7 5 5
Celda: 7 4 2
Celda: 7 3 8
Celda: 7 2 10
Celda: 7 1 1
Celda: 7 0 2


Celda: 6 9 6
Celda: 6 8 2
Celda: 6 7 7
Celda: 6 6 5
Celda: 6 5 3
Celda: 6 4 6
Celda: 6 3 3
Celda: 6 2 9
Celda: 6 1 1
Celda: 6 0 6


Celda: 5 9 8
Celda: 5 8 5
Celda: 5 7 5
Celda: 5 6 9
Celda: 5 5 5
Celda: 5 4 3
Celda: 5 3 6
Celda: 5 2 9
Celda: 5 1 9
Celda: 5 0 4


Celda: 4 9 9
Celda: 4 8 5
Celda: 4 7 9
Celda: 4 6 3
Celda: 4 5 9
Celda: 4 4 5
Celda: 4 3 6
Celda: 4 2 6
Celda: 4 1 8
Celda: 4 0 7


Celda: 3 9 7
Celda: 3 8 9
Celda: 3 7 2
Celda: 3 6 7
Celda: 3 5 8
Celda: 3 4 6
Celda: 3 3 4
Celda: 3 2 3
Celda: 3 1 1
Celda: 3 0 4


Celda: 2 9 5
Celda: 2 8 3
Celda: 2 7 5
Celda: 2 6 8
Celda: 2 5 4
Celda: 2 4 6
Celda: 2 3 2
Celda: 2 2 4
Celda: 2 1 8
Celda: 2 0 9


Celda: 1 9 9
Celda: 1 8 7
Celda: 1 7 5
Celda: 1 6 2
Celda: 1 5 1
Celda: 1 4 8
Celda: 1 3 2
Celda: 1 2 6
Celda: 1 1 8
Celda: 1 0 5


Celda: 0 9 4
Celda: 0 8 5
Celda: 0 7 7
Celda: 0 6 1
Celda: 0 5 5
Celda: 0 4 9
Celda: 0 3 6
Celda: 0 2 10
Celda: 0 1 6
Celda: 0 0 4
```

Comment: Saludos. Te falto incluir el error, mensaje de error y/o compartimiento que te hace indicar "no funciona"; una de las cosas de JavaScript es que todo es asíncrono; es decir que `mostrar(9);` no hay garantia se ejecute al terminar `recursivo(9);`. Una de las cosas de los recursivo es que puede llevar más tiempo el completarse que su fuera con un ciclo `for` o `while` (un bucle).

Comment: ya añadí lo que me sale cuando lo corro

Comment: podrias incluir el resultado esperado?

Comment: ya puse el resultado que debería de tener, es lo que me muestra cuando ejecuto el mismo algoritmo en java

Comment: la matriz `datos` es global por ende al  asignarla en `llenar()` se rellenara 1 vez y todas las demás veces que accedas a `datos` desde donde sea en este caso `enseñar()` seran igual `datos[]` por eso no cambia.!

Comment: @RobertoLeOr Eso es falso, porfavor no confundas al usuario, javascript no es todo asincrono, es mas, javascript es de naturaleza `sincrona` y esto se refuerza con el hecho de que en javascript corre entorno a 1 solo thread, javascript no tiene mas threads aquello que indicas no tiene nada que ver porque el codigo que el usuario muestra no lleva nada asincrono, se esta ejecutando en el orden deseado y por default.

Answer (score 0):

detecté varios problemas en tu código.

En la primera linea no estas inicializando una matriz

```
let datos = [10,10];
```

Lo que esta linea hace es crear un array con dos elementos [10, 10] y no una matriz de 10x10, puedes remplazar por un simple array vacio y no te preocupes por el tamaño ya que puede crecer dinamicamente.

```
let datos = [];
```

Al crecer dinámicamente significa que no puedes acceder directamente a una posición como datos[i][n] para asignar un valor aleatorio por que la fila [i] no existe, por lo tanto antes de llenarla debes inicializarla.

```
function recursivo(i){
  if(i < 0)
      return 0;
  else {
      datos[i] = []; // <- Aquí inicializas la fila
      llenar(i, 9);
      return recursivo(i-1);
  }
}
```

Otra observación es que no puedes acceder a los elementos de una matriz de esta manera

```
datos[i, n]
```

En su lugar debes acceder así

```
datos[i][n]
```

Una matriz es simplemente un array de arrays, entonces debes arreglar este método

```
function llenar(i,n){
  if(n<0)
    return 0;
  else {
    datos[i][n] = Math.round((Math.random()*10)+1); // <- Aquí
    return llenar(i,n-1);
  }
}
```

Y este método

```
function enseñar(i,n){
  if(n<0)
    return 0;
  else{
    console.log("Celda: " + i + " " + n + " " + datos[i][n]); // <- Aquí
    return enseñar(i,n-1);
  }
}
```

El script resultado sería este

```
let datos = [];

//Este es el método para recorrer las filas
function recursivo(i){
    if(i < 0)
        return 0;
    else{
        //llama a otro método recursivo para llenar cada fila
        datos[i] = [];
        llenar(i, 9);
        return recursivo(i-1);
    }
}

function llenar(i, n){
    if(n < 0)
        return 0;
    else{
        //lleno cada celda con un número aleatorio
        datos[i][n] = Math.round((Math.random()*10)+1);
        return llenar(i, n-1);
    }
}

//Método para recorrer las filas de la matriz
function mostrar(i){
    if(i<0)
        return 0;
    else{
        //Llamo a otro método recursivo para mostrar cada celda
        enseñar(i,9);        
        console.log("\n");
        return mostrar(i-1);
    }
}

//Método reursivo para mostrar las celdas
function enseñar(i,n){
    if(n<0)
        return 0;
    else{
        console.log("Celda: " + i + " " + n + " " + datos[i][n]);
        return enseñar(i,n-1);
    }
}

//Aquí llamo a los métodos, primero lleno la matriz
recursivo(9);
// Aquí muestro la matriz
mostrar(9);
```

Y daria como resultado esto

```
Celda: 9 9 11
Celda: 9 8 5
Celda: 9 7 10
Celda: 9 6 3
Celda: 9 5 2
Celda: 9 4 8
Celda: 9 3 3
Celda: 9 2 1
Celda: 9 1 11
Celda: 9 0 11


Celda: 8 9 7
Celda: 8 8 4
Celda: 8 7 9
Celda: 8 6 6
Celda: 8 5 9
Celda: 8 4 6
Celda: 8 3 3
Celda: 8 2 4
Celda: 8 1 6
Celda: 8 0 10


Celda: 7 9 8
Celda: 7 8 9
Celda: 7 7 5
Celda: 7 6 6
Celda: 7 5 2
Celda: 7 4 6
Celda: 7 3 7
Celda: 7 2 9
Celda: 7 1 10
Celda: 7 0 7


Celda: 6 9 8
Celda: 6 8 9
Celda: 6 7 2
Celda: 6 6 3
Celda: 6 5 5
Celda: 6 4 1
Celda: 6 3 10
Celda: 6 2 2
Celda: 6 1 7
Celda: 6 0 6


Celda: 5 9 5
Celda: 5 8 3
Celda: 5 7 6
Celda: 5 6 9
Celda: 5 5 7
Celda: 5 4 4
Celda: 5 3 4
Celda: 5 2 9
Celda: 5 1 9
Celda: 5 0 8


Celda: 4 9 4
Celda: 4 8 8
Celda: 4 7 2
Celda: 4 6 10
Celda: 4 5 9
Celda: 4 4 6
Celda: 4 3 6
Celda: 4 2 10
Celda: 4 1 1
Celda: 4 0 9


Celda: 3 9 8
Celda: 3 8 1
Celda: 3 7 3
Celda: 3 6 8
Celda: 3 5 7
Celda: 3 4 1
Celda: 3 3 2
Celda: 3 2 7
Celda: 3 1 3
Celda: 3 0 10


Celda: 2 9 6
Celda: 2 8 10
Celda: 2 7 4
Celda: 2 6 10
Celda: 2 5 2
Celda: 2 4 5
Celda: 2 3 6
Celda: 2 2 2
Celda: 2 1 6
Celda: 2 0 1


Celda: 1 9 7
Celda: 1 8 5
Celda: 1 7 1
Celda: 1 6 1
Celda: 1 5 4
Celda: 1 4 2
Celda: 1 3 10
Celda: 1 2 8
Celda: 1 1 8
Celda: 1 0 10


Celda: 0 9 4
Celda: 0 8 11
Celda: 0 7 9
Celda: 0 6 5
Celda: 0 5 6
Celda: 0 4 1
Celda: 0 3 9
Celda: 0 2 4
Celda: 0 1 5
Celda: 0 0 11
```